# Using public strSQL variable across all functions

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I've inherited an application which uses a public variable `strSQL` declared in a Module and uses this in all functions/subs where SQL queries are used. Presumably to avoid declaring the string in every function.

E.g.

```
Public strSQL as String

Public Shared Function DoStuff() 
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM XYZ"
    'Do SQL bit
End Function

Public Shared Function DoOtherStuff()
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ABC"
    'Do SQL bit
End Function
```

What would happen if after `DoStuff()` is called and `strSQL` is assigned `SELECT * FROM XYZ`, but before `strSQL` is used in the SQL bit, the other function `DoOtherStuff` is called and `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ABC"`.

Is it possible that `DoStuff` would return results from `"SELECT * FROM ABC"`?

Comment: That is very poor design. It isn't necessarily a problem unless your methods could be called on multiple threads, but you shouldn't open code up to potential issues like that without need. If the same value of that variable is not being used in multiple methods then the variable should not be accessible to multiple methods. If a local variable could achieve the same result then a local variable should be used. Scope and access should always be kept as limited as possible.

Comment: By the way, I notice that that variable is declared `Public`. is it being used outside the class? If not then its access is greater than required as well as its scope.  That said, you're appear to be accessing an instance field in `Shared` methods, which is not possible, so I think that you're actual code is probably slightly different.

Comment: Thanks. There is some multi-threading to be added, so I expect I will need to refactor this code to reduce the scope of the variables. The variable is declared in another module with a bunch of other public variables; I've edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of multithreading, it's best to lock parts of your code using this variable to avoid such situations, where two threads are sharing this variables and one thread tries to get data from `XYZ` table, while the other one tries to get data from `ABC` table.

As you saw, you can assign SQL statement, then other thread would assign other SQL statement, which previous thread would execute (expecting that it has statement originally assigned).

I would recommend to use something such as [`Semaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.7.2) to guarantee thread safety. Or you could also use [`SyncLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement) (C# `lock` equivalent in VB.NET).

Another way would be to use locally scoped variables in functions, so threads won't share the variable holding the statement.

Comment: Thanks for this, good to know. The multi-threading in this application doesn't actually set or change any variables (it mostly takes arguments to run database updates in the background), apart from this `strSQL` variable, so I don't need to lock anything if I refactor the `strSQL` variable scope.